# Quotient of generalised hypergeometric series ${}_3 F_2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, hypergeometric-function, monotone-functions

I have a function, defined for $x>0$ as

$$f(x) = (1+x)^3 \cdot \frac{{}_3F_2\left(\left\{1,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2x},\frac{1}{2x}\right\},\left\{1+\frac{1}{2x},\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{x}\right\},1\right)}{{}_3F_2\left(\left\{1,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2x},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2x}\right\},\left\{\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2x},\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{x}\right\},1\right)}$$

and I was wondering if it is possible to say anything about the quotient of the hypergeometric series?

In particular, I would like to say something about the monotonicity of $f$. I believe that $f$ is strictly increasing but I don't know how to show it.

I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Setting $\frac{1}{x}=u$ in your quotient would bring some simplification, dont you think ?

Comment: Besides, what is the motivation for this function ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JeanMarie I will give it a go. The motivation is that $f(x)$ appears as a critical parameter of a system and I've been trying to show that it is an increasing function for months and my every single attempt failed. I'd like to show it because then I could show that there are only two regimes that you can see in a system depending whether you're above or below $f(x)$

Comment: @JeanMarie I tried the substitution you suggested but I'm not sure how it simplifies things...

Comment: The functions in the quotient are rather similar. Specifically, if $$P(u,z)=\,_3F_2\left(1,\tfrac12 u,\tfrac12 z; \tfrac12 z+1,u+\tfrac12;1\right),$$ then $$f(x)=(1+x)^3\frac{P(u,u-1)}{P(u,u)},$$ where $u=1+\tfrac1x$

Comment: @clathratus do you think it is possible to say something about the monotonicity of $P(u,z)$ now? Especially with respect to $z$?

Comment: Using Euler's integral transform, it easy to see that $$P(u,z)=\frac{z}{2}\int_0^1 t^{z/2-1}\,_2F_1\left(1,\tfrac12u;u+\tfrac12;t\right)dt.$$ I will work on this integral more

Comment: The $_2F_1$ function in the integral is given by $$_2F_1\left(1,\tfrac12u;u+\tfrac12;t\right)=\frac{\Gamma(u+\tfrac12)}{\Gamma(\tfrac{u}{2})\Gamma(\tfrac{u+1}{2})}\int_0^1\frac{y^{u/2-1}(1-y)^{(u-1)/2}}{1-ty}dy$$

Comment: so, all in all, $$P(u,z)=\frac{z\Gamma(u+\tfrac12)}{2\Gamma(\tfrac{u}2)\Gamma(\tfrac{u+1}{2})}\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{t^{z/2-1}y^{u/2-1}(1-y)^{(u-1)/2}}{1-ty}dtdy$$

Comment: The cases $z=u,u-1$ are probably easier to compute, given that the exponent of $z/2-1$ will become $u/2-1, (u-3)/2$

Answer (score 3):

This function
$$f(x) = (1+x)^3 \cdot \frac{{}_3F_2\left(\left\{1,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2x},\frac{1}{2x}\right\},\left\{1+\frac{1}{2x},\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{x}\right\},1\right)}{{}_3F_2\left(\left\{1,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2x},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2x}\right\},\left\{\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2x},\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{x}\right\},1\right)}$$
can be read properly and wrongly. Reading it properly it is noticed that the coefficients do not reduce in a nice way. This leads to having to expand the series and "do some division". In this manor it can be developed into
\begin{align}
f(x) &= (x+1)^2 \, \left( 1 - \frac{2 \, x^2 \, (x+1)}{(2 x+1)(3 x + 1) (3 x + 2)^2} \right. \\ 
& \hspace{5mm} \left. - \frac{2 \, x^2 \, (x+1)(224 x^5 +417 x^4 + 310 x^3 + 113 x^2 + 23 x + 2)}{(2 x+1)(3 x+1)^2 (4 x+1) (5 x+1)(3 x+2)^2 (5 x +2)} + \cdots \right).
\end{align}

In reading the problem wrongly a nice pattern can be obtained as seen by the following. Given
$$f_{0}(x) = (1+x)^3 \cdot \frac{{}_3F_2\left(\left\{1,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2x},\frac{1}{2x}\right\},\left\{1+\frac{1}{2x},\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2 x}\right\},1\right)}{{}_3F_2\left(\left\{1,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2x},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2x}\right\},\left\{\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2x},\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2 x}\right\},1\right)}$$
then $ f_{0}(x) = (x+1)^2 \, g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), $ where
$$ g(x) = \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 n +x)(2 n + x +1)}}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 k + x + 1)^2}} = 2 \, \frac{\psi\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\psi^{(1)}\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)}. $$
This leads to
$$ f_{0}(x) = 2 \, (x+1)^2 \, \frac{\psi\left(\frac{x+1}{2 x}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{1}{2 x}\right)}{\psi^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{2 x} + \frac{1}{2}\right)}, $$
where $\psi(x)$ is the digamma function and $\psi^{(1)}$ is the first derivative of the digamma function (trigamma function).

Proof of $g(x)$:

Using $$ (x)_{2n} = 2^{2 n} \, \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)_{n} \, \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)_{n}, $$ where $(a)_{n}$ is the Pochhammer symbol, then
\begin{align}
\frac{\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)_{n} \, \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)_{n}}{\left(\frac{x+2}{2}\right)_{n} \, \left(\frac{x+3}{2}\right)_{n}} &= \frac{(x)_{2 n}}{(x+2)_{2 n}} = \frac{\Gamma(2 n + x) \, \Gamma(x+2)}{\Gamma(x) \, \Gamma(2 n + x + 2)} \\
&= \frac{x \, (x+1)}{(2 n + x) (2 n + x + 1)} = \frac{x \, (x+1)}{4} \, \left(\frac{1}{n + \frac{x}{2}} - \frac{1}{n + \frac{x+1}{2}} \right)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)_{n}}{\left(\frac{x+3}{2}\right)_{n}}\right)^2 &= \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^2 \, \frac{1}{\left(n + \frac{x+1}{2}\right)^2}
\end{align}
give
\begin{align}
{}_{3}F_{2}\left(1, \, \frac{x}{2}, \, \frac{x+1}{2}; \, \frac{x+2}{2}, \, \frac{x+3}{2}; \, 1 \right) &= \frac{x (x+1)}{4} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n + \frac{x}{2}} - \frac{1}{n + \frac{x+1}{2}} \right) \\
&= \frac{x (x+1)}{4} \, \left( \psi\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \right) \\
{}_{3}F_{2}\left(1, \, \frac{x+1}{2}, \, \frac{x+1}{2}; \, \frac{x+3}{2}, \, \frac{x+3}{2}; \, 1 \right) &= \frac{(x+1)^2}{4} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(n + \frac{x+1}{2}\right)^2} \\
&= \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^2 \, \psi^{'}\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)
\end{align}
from which $g(x)$ is obtained.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I'm just not sure if we can actually rewrite $f(x)$ that way... I tried to derive $g(x)$ but I couldn't so I tried to see if $f(x)$ and the new version of $f(x)$ match for certain values, and for example when $x=1$ they give two different values... Would you mind elaborating more on how you obtained $g(x)$? Thanks!

Comment: The numerator of your expression  $\psi\left(\frac{x+1}{2 x}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{1}{2 x}\right)$ appears in different questions for example [this one](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h435647p2458179) obtained by the formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/. This remark can be of some help for Mathic.

Comment: @Leucippus thanks for the explanation! It's a shame that it seems that my function cannot be simplified in any way... But I agree that if you read the function incorrectly and do the computations that you did, the formula you arrived at is quite remarkable!